# Rails Multiple Table Inheritance delete parent on child deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using active_record-acts_as gem to implement multiple table inheritance. My scenario:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
   actable
end

class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :Vehicle
end

class Train < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :Vehicle
end
```

Whenever I create an instance of Plane or Train, a corresponding Vehicle is created, however, whenever I delete a Plane, the corresponding Vehicle row is not deleted.

Is it possible to make it so whenever a child is deleted, the parent row gets deleted as well?

Comment: You can try to use the active record before_destroy/after_destroy callbacks

Comment: Do you mean to delete it manually on a callback method? I'm asking if there's an automatic way...

Comment: Take a look at [options here](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as/blob/master/lib/active_record/acts_as/relation.rb#L10). You should use the dependent: :destroy

Comment: did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

From [README documentation](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as):

> `acts_as` support all `has_one` options, where defaults are there:
>   `as: :actable, dependent: :destroy, validate: false, autosave: true`

So:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
   actable
end

class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :Vehicle, dependent: :destroy
end

class Train < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :Vehicle, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I recommend reading gem's documentation before/when using it, especially, when issues/questions occurs as to it's usage.

Comment: I did read the documentation, tried your code before asking the initial question and didn't work. Just in case I tried it again before responding to this and still does not work. I delete a Plane but a record still exists on Vehicle

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake on my behalf from the beginning.

The reason why records weren't getting deleted is because I was calling Plane.delete instead of Plane.destroy.

Regards.